# Pygame: error using sprite

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Hey i'm working on a little game project on pygame, but everytime i try to run my code i get an error when he gets to using my sprite:

```
class Sprite:
    def _init_(self, xposition, yposition, name):
        self.x = xposition
        self.y = yposition
        self.bitmap = image.load(name)
        self.bitmap.set_colorkey ((0,0,0))
    def set_position(self, xposition, yposition):
        self.x = xposition
        self.y = yposition
    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.x, self.y))
```

and here is how i call it

```
hero = Sprite(20,400, 'spaceship.bmp')
herobullet = Sprite(0,480, 'bulete.bmp')
enemiebullet = Sprite(0,480, 'bulete.bmp')
```

Update

here is the error message that comes up in the commad line

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_debugger.py:720: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if filename == frame.f_code.co_filename or (not bound and breakpoint_path_match(filename, frame.f_code.co_filename)):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py:265: RuntimeWarning: use surfarray: no module named numpy or Numeric found
(ImportError: no module named numpy or Numeric found)
  obj_repr = repr(obj)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py:265: RuntimeWarning: use sndarray: no module named numpy or Numeric found
(ImportError: no module named numpy or Numeric found)
  obj_repr = repr(obj)
The program '[6344] python.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

here is the full code

```
from pygame import *
import random
from Space_invader import *

#create the sprite for both enemy and hero
class Sprite:
    def _init_(self, xposition, yposition, name):
        self.x = xposition
        self.y = yposition
        self.bitmap = image.load(name)
        self.bitmap.set_colorkey ((0,0,0))
    def set_position(self, xposition, yposition):
        self.x = xposition
        self.y = yposition
    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.x, self.y))

# colision detection betwee two 32*32 sprite
def Intersect(o1_x, o1_y, o2_x, o2_y):
    if (o1_x > o2_x - 32) and (o1_x < o2_x + 32) and (o1_y > o2_y - 32) and (o1_y < o2_y + 32):
                return 1
    else:
                return 0 

#initialise pygame 
init()
screen = display.set_mode((640,480))
key.set_repeat(1,1)     #make sure you can press the same key more then one and that there is a delay between each action
display.set_caption('UON Invader') #set windows name
background = image.load('background.png') #load background picture
hero = Sprite(20,400, 'spaceship.bmp')
herobullet = Sprite(0,480, 'bulete.bmp')
enemiebullet = Sprite(0,480, 'bulete.bmp')
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Can you give us the exact error?

Answer (score 2):

First of all always include your adequate error message so we know where to search :)
So one possible error could be the

```
self.bitmap = image.load(name)
```

If you have imported pygame like this:

```
import pygame
```

This line of code should be changed to :

```
self.bitmap = pygame.image.load(name)
```

Hope that helps!
Alex

(edit) after searching a bit for your runtime error, a probable solution would be to download and install this module [Link](https://numpy.org/).

(edit2) After searching for you issue I think that you need to check your program for any unicode or non-asci characters. They would look something like this "çö". See if you have inserted any of these characters anywhere by mistake and try to fix it :)

Comment: Would I be correct if I said that you could also do this by changing `import pygame` to `from pygame import *`?

Comment: i import it like with the from method

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with your import statements.. Can you post the full code?

Comment: i just installed numpy and i know get a new error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_debugger.py:296: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  handlers = self.handler_cache.get(cur_frame.f_code.co_filename)
The program '[7692] python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: @FellowRémi After searching for you issue I think that you need to check your program for any unicode or non-asci characters. They would look something like this "çö". See if you have inserted any of these characters anywhere by mistake and try to fix it :)

Comment: which one of these is not an ASCII " or '

Comment: What you should do is check the ascii table here http://www.asciitable.com/ where you can find all the standard ascii characters (look the chr or char columns) and if you find a character in your code that is not included in the standard  128 ascii characters you should remove it. Hope that helped :)

Comment: to do so i used grep in unix so im 100% sure all characters are ASCII